# PHP - make a link active based on folder name

Tags: php, html, css

This is probably an easy one but I'm just getting started with PHP.

I'm attempting to create a universal header and want to use PHP to make the links have a CSS class based on the folder structure of the currant url.

The idea is to have 3 levels of navigation, level 1 will be set by the first folder, level 2 set by the subfolder, and level 3 will be set by the name of the php file.

For example if you have the url www.mysite.com/Home/Aboutus/History.php?id=1

The option "Home" will be active on level 1 of the menu
"AboutUs" will be active on the second Level
and "History" will be active on the 3rd Level

html

```
<a href="#"><div class="Menu-1-Button">
<p class="Menu-1-Button-Text">Option1A</p></div></a>

<a href="#"><div class="Menu-1-Button">
<p class="Menu-1-Button-Text">Option1B</p></div></a>

<a href="#"><div class="Menu-1-Button">
<p class="Menu-1-Button-Text">Option1C</p></div></a>

</div>

<div id="Selected-Option1A">
<div class="Sub-Menu-2">

<a href="#"><div class="Menu-2-Button">
<p class="Menu-2-Button-Text">Option2A</p></div></a>

<a href="#"><div class="Menu-2-Button">
<p class="Menu-2-Button-Text">Option2B</p></div></a>

<a href="#"><div class="Menu-2-Button">
<p class="Menu-2-Button-Text">Option2C</p></div></a>


</div>

<div id="Sub-Menu-3">

<a href="#"><div class="Menu-3-Button">
<p class="Menu-3-Button-Text">Option3A</p></div>

<a href="#"><div class="Menu-3-Button">
<p class="Menu-3-Button-Text">Option3B</p></div>

<a href="#"><div class="Menu-3-Button">
<p class="Menu-3-Button-Text">Option3C</p></div>

</div>
</div>

<div id="Selected-Option1B">
<div class="Sub-Menu-2">

<a href="#"><div class="Menu-2-Button">
<p class="Menu-2-Button-Text">Option2A</p></div></a>

<a href="#"><div class="Menu-2-Button">
<p class="Menu-2-Button-Text">Option2B</p></div></a>

<a href="#"><div class="Menu-2-Button">
<p class="Menu-2-Button-Text">Option2C</p></div></a>


</div>

<div id="Sub-Menu-3">

<a href="#"><div class="Menu-3-Button">
<p class="Menu-3-Button-Text">Option3A</p></div>

<a href="#"><div class="Menu-3-Button">
<p class="Menu-3-Button-Text">Option3B</p></div>

<a href="#"><div class="Menu-3-Button">
<p class="Menu-3-Button-Text">Option3C</p></div>

</div>
</div>
```

On my header the bottom 2 menu levels will be changed depending on the option selected on the first menu level, to do this ill give each Selected-Optionx div a property of display:none  and use a similar technique to the active class to give one of the Selected-Option1x divs a class of display:block depending on the option selected on the first menu level.

So basically I want to know how to give something a class of "active" depending on the currant folders in the URL using PHP.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean Strawberry folders?

Comment: @user3258803 its a joke, [currant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribes) is a type of berry. You meant current, the present.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly I don't think you're headed the right way here.

It is certainly possible to do what you request from PHP, but you will end up with a crappy, complex and monolithic structure.

If you implement that framework, it will force you to twist your contents to fit this arbitrary 3 levels structure. You will most likely end up with contrieved contents that have been put there only because the tool you designed forced you to do so.

Besides, you will end up with a one-page application that will be filled with hidden sub-pages.
It will take longer to load and consume more resources, with no added benefit since you will not be able to display anything meaningful until the whole document is loaded.

All this being said, here is a bit of code that might show what it could look like:

```
$tree = array (
    "optionA" => array (
        "optionA1" => array (
            "optionA1a" => "",
            "optionA1b" => "",
            "optionA1c" => ""),
        "optionA2" => array (
            "optionA2a" => "",
            "optionA2b" => "",
            "optionA2c" => ""),
        "optionA3" => array (
            "optionA3a" => "",
            "optionA3b" => "",
            "optionA3c" => "")),
    "optionB" => array (
        "optionB1" => array (
            "optionB1a" => "",
            "optionB1b" => "",
            "optionB1c" => ""),
        "optionB2" => array (
            "optionB2a" => "",
            "optionB2b" => "",
            "optionB2c" => ""),
        "optionB3" => array (
            "optionB3a" => "",
            "optionB3b" => "",
            "optionB3c" => "")));

foreach ($tree as $n1 => $l2)
foreach ($l2   as $n2 => $l3)
foreach ($l3   as $n3 => $junk)
{
    echo "<a href=http::/whatever.what/$n1/$n2/$n3.html>...whatever...</a>";
}
```

If you want a word of advice, give up on the dream of making a generic framework.
Genericity is good for selling things, and a pain to implement.
Leave that to the marketing guys.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly but this is how I use one file for all navigation and still retain any `class="active"` stuff I may have.

Somewhere in the header:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

On each link, change names accordingly

```
<a <?php if($url == '/studentdb/index.php'){ echo "class='active'";} ?> href="index.php">
```

**EDIT**
If you wanted to echo the `class active` when the user is in a directory regardless of the page you could use `strpos` or `stristr` to check the $url and if returns positive then you echo class active. I have used the `!==` to mean *if not false*, i.e. true.

```
<a <?php if(strpos($url, 'myDirectory') !== false){ echo "class='active'";} ?> href="index.php">
```

Note: [Stristr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) is case Insensitive whereas [Strpos](http://www.php.net/strpos) is case Sensitive

Comment: Ok that gets me part of the way there, but how would you get it to ignore the querystring?

Comment: And how would you make something "active" regardless of what file it is within the folder "studentdb".

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean when you say `ignore the querystring`. And to make it active regardless of what file it is inside that folder you can use `strpos` or `stristr`. Check my updated answer for details.